# VBA Application.Run returns error 1004 The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA project which uses two workbooks on the same time. In workbook A, a module calls a module from workbook B like this:

```
If oED Is Nothing Then 
      Set oED = Application.Run("'" & workbookB & "'!wbB.MainModule.InitDatabaseObject")
End If
```

This has previously worked fine, but suddenly (apparently) this line of code doesn't find the module/macro in the other workbook.

I get this error message

> Error 1004. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all
>   macros may be disabled.

I have tried to:

- Clear the macro settings in Excel
- Clean the workbook (using a tool)
- Delete ActiveX cache files (*.exd files)

When my work colleague runs the same workbooks on his computer, this works fine.

Does anyone have a clue what's going on?

Br,
Johan

Comment: Perhaps the path is wrong for your computer?

Comment: Make sure  `wbB` and `MainModule` weren't renamed.

Comment: @Rory The paths shouldn't be relevant as they are in same folder

Comment: @Vincent G But they are still the same on my colleagues computer as he ran the exact same workbooks

Comment: Is the other workbook open at the time, and what is your `Application.AutomationSecurity` set to?

Comment: @Rory The workbook is not opened at that time. But I have tried to have it opened at the same time too, but it doesn't help. The AutomationSecurity is set to low.

Comment: Why is the `wbB` part there as a matter of interest? I'd expect just `'workbook name'!module.macro` so you appear to have more than necessary there.

Comment: @Rory Good question. It's a legacy project I have inherited, so I don't know why it's been put there. But removing it doesn't help.

Comment: Is `workbookB` just a workbook name, or does it include a path too? Also, I assume it includes the file extension?

Comment: @Rory It's just a workbook name. No path. Includes .xlsm extension. Doesn't help if I rewrite it as actual Application.Run("'"workbookB.xlsm!wbB.MainModule.InitDatabaseObject")

Comment: If the workbok is open and using `Application.Run("'"workbookB.xlsm!MainModule.InitDatabaseObject")` doesn't work, then I'd have to assume that your automationsecurity is actually disabling macros. How did you verify the setting?

Comment: @Rory During debugging at the Application.Run codeline, Quick watch on Applicaiton object and on AutmationSecurity variable.

Comment: @Rory But I just found out to my surprise that the workbook B doesn't compile! But how come it worked on my work colleagues computer is a mystery, as it also should not have compiled then.

Answer (score 1):

Found the culprit. The workbookB simply didn't compile. After correcting it and making sure it compiled the Application.Run worked fine.